# partial cell match in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I am trying to do a partial match within a column. I am using the formula `=MATCH("*"&LEFT(B2,5)&"*",B:B,0)`. and then dragging the formula all the way to the bottom. So it is taking the first 5 letters from left of a field of Column B and trying to do a match. Is there a way that it can take the letters after the first two characters of the Col B fields and then do a match?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected outcome?  Also you are matching a part of a cell in the same range,  the match function you have will return 2 then the next will return 3 and so on.  So a little more explanation would be needed as to what you expect as an outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the first two characters in column B for a match, you may want to use a helper column with a formula like

=mid(B2,3,99)

and then perform the Match on the helper column.